# Field extensions and Galois goup

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $p$ b a prime, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $f=x^{p^n}-x-1\in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ be irreducible. Let $a\in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ be a root pf $f$.

We have that $[\mathbb{F}_p(a):\mathbb{F}_p]=p^n$, where $\{1,a,\ldots , a^{p^n-1}\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{F}_p(a)/\mathbb{F}_p$, so $\mathbb{F}_p(a)=\{c_0+c_1a+\ldots +c_{p^n-1}a^{p^n-1} : c_i\in \mathbb{F}_p\}$. There are $p$ choices for each $c_i$. So, there are $p\cdot p\cdot \ldots \cdot p=p^{p^n}$ choices for $(c_0, c_1, \ldots c_{p^n-1})$. Therefore, we have that $|\mathbb{F}_p(a)|=p^{p^n}$, right?

We have that $\mathbb{F}_p(a)$ contains all the roots of $f$.

We also have  that for each $b\in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, $a+b$ is a root of $f$ and that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}\leq \mathbb{F}_p(a)$ and $n=p^i$ for some $i\in \{0, 1, \ldots , n\}$.

Then I want to show that $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_p(α)/\mathbb{F}_{p^n} )$ is cyclic and let $\tau$ be a generator. I want to calculate also the order of $\tau$ as a function of $i$.

We have that $|\mathbb{F}_{p^n}|=p^n$ and $|\mathbb{F}_p(a)|=p^{p^n}$. From the corollary [image]

we have that $\mathbb{F}_p(α)/\mathbb{F}_{p^n} $ is Galois, $n\mid p^n$, which is true since $n=p^i$. From the corollary we also have that $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_p(α)/\mathbb{F}_{p^n} )$ is cyclic and is generated by the automorphism $\tau (x)=x^{p^n}$.

> Do we calculate the order of $\tau$ as follows?
>     $$\tau (x)=x^{p^n} \\ \tau^2 (x)=\tau( x^{p^n})=(\tau
>   (x))^{p^n}=(x^{p^n})^{p^n}=x^{p^n\cdot p^n}=x^{p^{2n}} \\ \ldots \\
>  \tau^k(x)=x^{p^{kn}}$$

So that $m$ is the order, $m$ has to be the smallest integer such that
  $\tau^m(x)=x \Rightarrow x^{p^{mn}}=x$. Since $x\in \mathbb{F}_p(a)$
  and $| \mathbb{F}_p(a)|=p^{p^n}$ we have that $x=x^{p^{p^n}}$.  So, we
  get that $x^{p^{mn}}=x^{p^{p^n}} \Rightarrow p^{mn}=p^{p^n}\Rightarrow
  mn=p^n\Rightarrow m=\frac{p^n}{n}$.

Then independent from that I want to calculate a simple expression of $\tau^k(a)$.

I have done the following: 
Since $\tau$ is a generator of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_p(α)/\mathbb{F}_{p^n} )$ that means that $\tau$ is a $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$-automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_p(a)$ that maps to a root of $f$ to an other root, right?

> So, we have that $\tau (a)=a+b$. Therefore, we get the following: 
>     $$\tau^2(a)=\tau(a+b)=\tau (a)+\tau (b)=a+b+b=a+2b \\
>   \tau^3(a)=\tau(\tau^2(a))=\tau (a+2b)=\tau (a)+\tau (2b)=a+b+2b=a+3b
>   \\ \ldots \\ \tau^k(a)=a+kb$$ Is this correct?

The order of $\tau$ is the smallest integer $m$ such that
  $\tau^m(a)=a\Rightarrow a+mb=a$. Does this imply that $m=p$ ?

Comment: How can $x^{p^e}-1$ be irreducible?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo at f. I corrected it.

Comment: (1) Galois group of finite field extensions are always cyclic.
(2) Tthe order of  a generator will be the degree of your extension.

Comment: So, is it as follows? $$\text{ord}\tau=|\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_p(α)/\mathbb{F}_{p^n} )|=\frac{|\mathbb{F}_p(α)|}{|\mathbb{F}_{p^n}|}=\frac{p^{p^n}}{p^n}=p^{p^n-n}$$ @MathChat

Comment: What have I done wrong? Is it not correct that $|\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_p(α)/\mathbb{F}_{p^n} )|=\frac{|\mathbb{F}_p(α)|}{|\mathbb{F}_{p^n}|}$ ? @MathChat

Comment: How could we calculate the degree? @MathChat

Comment: At the end I want to show that $n=1$ or $n=2$. About the degree, at a next question we have to calculate the $[\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p^n}]$, so I suppose that in this question we have to calculate $\text{ord}\tau$ without using $[\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p^n}]$. Or isn't there an other way? @MathChat

Comment: All I can tell is that  when $f$ is irreducible, then you have
$[\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha): \mathbb{F}_{p^n}]=\frac{p^n}{n}$, and this same number will be the order of the generator of the correposponding Galois group.

Comment: Could we find the order also as follows? $$\tau (x)=x^{p^n} \\ \tau^2 (x)=\tau( x^{p^n})=(\tau (x))^{p^n}=(x^{p^n})^{p^n}=x^{p^n\cdot p^n}=x^{p^{2n}} \\ \ldots \\ \tau^k(x)=x^{p^{kn}}$$ 

To find the order of $\tau$ we have to find the smallest interger $m$ such that $\tau^m(x)=x \Rightarrow x^{p^{mn}}=x$. But which is this $m$ ? @MathChat

Comment: Yes. Then you arrive that $p^{mn}=p^{p^n}$, which gives you $m=\frac{p^n}{n}$.

Comment: Do we have that because $x\in \mathbb{F}_p(a)$ and $| \mathbb{F}_p(a)|=p^{p^n}$ ? @MathChat

Comment: At my question at the last part is it correct to get that the ordr is $p$ ? But why do we get an other order as the previous one? @MathChat

Comment: Mary, are you going after something like what is explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/122274/11619) or possibly [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/579659/11619).

Comment: I have to follow some specific steps to get to the desired results. 
Are the two parts in my questions, that I quoted, correct? Why do I get two different orders? Shouldn't they be the same? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Both parts are correct, and since $m = p$ and $m = \frac{p^n}{n}$, we must have $n = 1$ for $p>2$, and $n = 1$ or $2$ for $p = 2$.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!! :-) @SSepehr