# Basis of factors for large degree polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, factoring, mathematica

In $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the polynomial $x^{2^6}+x+1$ or $x^{64}+x+1$ factors into  $x^4+x+1$, $x^{12}+x^9+x^5+x^2+1$, $x^{12}+x^9+x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1$, $x^{12}+x^9+x^8+x^5+1$, $x^{12}+x^9+x^8+x^5+x^4+x+1$, $x^{12}+x^9+x^8+x^6+x^3+x^2+1$.  Below, under $1+x+x^{64}$, you can see the degree 12 factors arranged as columns, followed by the basis (a gray bar separates factors and basis). The same is shown for $n$ from 5 to 13.

[image: factors and basis]

In $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $x^{2^n}+x+1$ has many factors of degree $2 n$ and the number of basis elements always seems to be $n-2$. Here are pictures of the basis for $n$ from 7 to 18.

[image: basis in z2]

Here's Mathematica code for the first image.

```
data = Table[Module[{ polynomials, len, polyandbasis},
  polynomials = Last[Sort[SplitBy[SortBy[CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ (First /@ 
  FactorList[x^(2^power) + x + 1, Modulus -> 2]), {Length[#], Reverse[#]} &], Length[#] &]]];
  len = Length[polynomials[[1]]];
  polyandbasis = Flatten /@ Transpose[{ 3 Transpose[polynomials], Table[{0, 1, 0}, {len}], 
  3 Transpose[Select[RowReduce[polynomials, Modulus -> 2], Total[#] > 0 &]]}];
  Column[{Text[x^(2^power) + x + 1], ArrayPlot[polyandbasis, PixelConstrained -> True, 
  ImageSize -> {800, 2 len + 4}, Frame -> False]}, Alignment -> Center]], {power, 5, 13}];
Column[{Row[Take[data, 6], Spacer[30]], Row[Take[data, {7, 8}], Spacer[60]], Row[Take[data, {9}]]}]
```

First question: Does the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ polynomial $x^{2^n}+x+1$ have a particular name? It has a lot of nice properties.

I'd like to make pictures of higher order basis elements. Unfortunately, Mathematica doesn't want to Factor $x^{1048576}+x+1$, claiming it's out of bounds. Also, PolynomialGCD doesn't like high exponents. I've looked at the [Cantor–Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm) and other factorization methods over finite fields, but didn't readily understand them.

Is there some clever way to get the basis of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factors of $x^{2^n}+x+1$ for $n$ from 19 to 120 in Mathematica? Is there some nice way of quickly getting some of the degree $2n$ factors.

Comment: In a cosmic joke, the sequence of boxed diagrams tends toward this diagram: `¯\(ツ)/¯`

Comment: I don't have the time delve into this deeply, but [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/581159/11619) gives some basic facts about factoring polynomials of the form $x^{2^r}+x+1$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$. I don't know if that leads to an explanation.

Comment: But this looks cool (+1). Just to be sure, what exactly you mean by *a basis* here?

Comment: The basis:  convert polynomials like 1+x+x^4 into coefficient lists (1,1,0,0,1), then row reduce all the lists.

Comment: maybe it's because it's late but I don't see any link whatsoever between the given factorisation of $x^{2^6}+x+1$ and the second picture. Neither on the left nor on the right (whatever "basis" means)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a full answer, just the fruits of my first session thinking about this question. The main reason for posting this is that I can prove the following:

**Result 1.** The described basis has size at most $n-2$.

[My older answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/581159/11619) allows us to give the following description for the degree $2n$ factors of $x^{2^n}+x+1$.

- Assume that $p(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\cdots+a_2x^2+a_1x+1$ is irreducible (take notice of the terms of degrees $0,n-1,n$). Then the polynomial $p(x^2+x)$ is an irreducible degree $2n$ factor of $x^{2^n}+x+1$. This follows from the description in the linked answer as the (negative of) coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is the trace of the zeros of $p(x)$.
- All the irreducible degree $2n$ factors of $x^{2^n}+x+1$ are gotten following the recipe of the previous bullet for some such irreducible polynomial $p(x)$. See the linked answer again.
- Let $p(x)$ be one of the polynomials from the first bullet. Because $x+1$ is not a factor of $p(x)$, there is an odd number of non-zero terms in $p(x)$. Consequently the difference $$p(x)-(1+x^{n-1}+x^n)$$ has an even number of terms, all with degrees in the range $[1,n-2]$. Therefore $p(x)$ is in the linear span of $x+x^2,x+x^3,\ldots,x+x^{n-2},1+x^{n-1}+x^n$.

**Proof.** (of Result 1.) Consider the linear mapping 
$R:\Bbb{F}_2[x]\to\Bbb{F}_2[x]$ given by the formula
$$
R(f(x))=f(x^2+x).
$$
The third bullet above implies that the irreducible degree $2n$ factors of $x^{2^n}+x+1$
are all in the linear span of
$$
R(x+x^2),R(x+x^3),\ldots,R(x+x^{n-2}),R(1+x^{n-1}+x^n).
$$

There are $n-2$ polynomials in this list so the subspace of $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$ spanned by the said factors has dimension at most $n-2$.
**QED.**

I also record the following trivial fact for future use because it may play a role.

> Because $\deg R(f(x))=2\deg f(x)$ for all polynomials $f(x)$, we see that the linear mapping $R$ is injective.

Comment: We can probably count the number of irreducible polynomials $p(x)$ of degree $n$ appearing here. Basically the claim that the basis has size exactly $n-2$ is to prove that the polynomials $p(x)-1-x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}$ span all of $\langle x+x^2,x+x^3,\ldots,x+x^{n-2}\rangle$. This is very likely for all large $n$, and can be checked manually (or CAS-aided) for small $n$, but the types of results about the distribution of irreducible polynomials I can recall right away don't seem to bite :-(