# Prove that $x^{p^{n}}-x-a$ is reducible over GF(p).

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $p$ is a prime,$n≥1$ and $n \nmid p^{n}$.Suppose $a\in GF(p)$.Prove that $x^{p^{n}}-x-a$ is reducible over $GF(p)$.

I just have no idea. Please help me,thanks!

Comment: @Bart Michels It is from my text book.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/579659/11619) for a bit more discussion. This is, indeed, a fun application of Galois theory of finite fields, but we have studied this question quite well I think.

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\GF}{GF}$It seems that a slightly more general result holds true. This states that

> for a prime $p$, if $n > 2$, or $n = 2$ and $p > 2$, then the polynomial $x^{p^{n}}-x-a$ is *reducible* over $\GF(p)$.

Suppose $f = x^{p^{n}}-x-a$ is *irreducible* over $F = \GF(p)$. (In particular, of course, $a \ne 0$.)

Then, if $\beta$ is a root of $f$, we have that $E = F[\beta]$ is a field with $p^{p^{n}}$ elements.

Since $f(\beta) = 0$, we have
$$
\beta^{p^{n}} = \beta + a,
\quad
(\beta^{p^{n}})^{p^{n}} = \beta^{p^{2 n}} = \beta^{p^{n}} + a = \beta + 2 a,
\quad
\dots
\quad
\beta^{p^{p n}} = \beta + p a = \beta.
$$
It follows that $\beta$ lies in the field $L$ with $p^{p n}$ elements, as $\beta$ is a root of the polynomial $x^{p^{p n}} - x \in F[x]$. But then $E \subseteq L$, so that $p^{n} \mid p n$, and $p^{n-1} \mid n$. This is only possible (if I'm not mistaken) for $n = 1$, and any $p$, or for $p = n = 2$.

And in fact, for $a \ne 0$, the polynomial $x^{p} - x - a$ is irreducible over $F$. And the polynomial $x^{4} - x - 1$ is irreducible over $\GF(2)$.

Comment: +1. This is a nice trick. The question is unfortunately a duplicate, so I had to close it as such.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, you were absolutely right. I learned something valuable from the previous posts on the matter, thanks!