# Irreducibility of $x^{2^n}+x+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to solve this problem from Hungerford V.5.9.

I have to show $x^{2^n}+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ if n>2.

I would appreciate some hint cause I don't know how to start with it.Thanks!

EDITED:
This question is completely different to 
[On irreducible factors of $x^{2^n}+x+1$ in $\mathbb Z_2[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508920/on-irreducible-factors-of-x2nx1-in-mathbb-z-2x)
The reason is obvious, i m asking if this polynomial is irreducible. In the other question, we assume it is reducible without showing it.

Comment: do you mean $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: It doesn't seem true: $(x^6+x^5+x^3+1)(x^2+x+1)=x^{2^3}+x+1$.

Comment: @Jlamprong no...is it obvious in $\mathbb{Z}_2$??

Comment: For any odd $n>1$ its wrong: $x^{2^n}+x+1=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (x^2+x+1)^{2^k}=(x^2+x+1)\cdot(\cdots)$ (the first equality is a telescoping sum by freshman's dream)

Comment: @zozoens $(x^6+x^5+x^3+1)(x^2+x+1) = x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

Comment: @zozoens, MAPLE tells me that you re not right, this multiplication of polynomials gives $x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

Comment: @John sorry, I forgot the $x^2$ term, so we have $(x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2+1)(x^2+x+1)$

Comment: @zozoens Makes more sense now. :)

Comment: @TooOldForMath could you explain this?

Comment: I'm a little confused cause it seems obvious that @zozoens is right but this implies Hungerford exercise is wrong...

Comment: Maybe the exercise is for $n$ even...

Comment: @zozoens: No the same trick works for any $n$ that has an odd factor. So it can only be true for $n=2^m$.

Comment: I don't understand the edit. In the other question it is shown that the irreducible factors of this polynomial are of degree $\ge 2n$. So if $2^n>2n$, i.e. if $n>2$, then this polynomial is reducible, and any exercise asking you to show that it is irreducible is just wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is not true. Assume $n>1$ is odd. Then

$$
\begin{align}
x^{2^n}+x+1 &= (x^{2^n}+x^{2^{n-1}}+1)+(x^{2^{n-1}}+x^{2^{n-2}}+1)+\cdots+(x^2+x+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x^{2^{k+1}}+x^{2^k}+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (x^2+x+1)^{2^k}\\
&= (x^2+x+1)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (x^2+x+1)^{2^k-1}\right)
\end{align}
$$

We used that $n$ is odd in the first equality, where there are $n$ ones on the right side, thus summing to $1$.

*Note:* The same argument can be used to show that $x^{2^n}+x+1$ is reducible whenever $n$ has an odd factor greater than $1$. Therefore it can only be irreducible if $n=2^m$.

Comment: This works for odd $n$, as the third roots of unity are then zeros of this polynomial, and your calculation verifies that the third cyclotomic polynomial is a factor. However, the polynomial is never irreducible, when $n>2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen why is the polynomial never irreducible, when n>2?

Comment: @TiWen: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/508932/11619) to the question this is a duplicate of. Tip about the site: If a question is marked as a duplicate of another, older question, the older version is often (but not always!) a good source for extra information.