# The reducibility of polynomial $x^{2^n}+x+1$ over $Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I meet the problem in Hungerford's Algebra, page 282 as follows:

If $n>2$, then the polynomial $x^{2^n}+x+1$ is reducible over $Z_2$ .

I have no any idea on this. But I really want to know how to prove this.

Thanks!

Comment: These question seems to be similar (the same?): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663398/irreducibility-of-x2nx1-over-mathbbz-2 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508920/on-irreducible-factors-of-x2nx1-in-mathbb-z-2x

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate. The answers to questions in Martin's links do settle this question.

Comment: To bridge the tiny gap: For $n>2$, we have $2^n>2n$, and [the second link by Martin Sleziak](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508920/) proves that all irreducible factors have degree dividing $2n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I am sorry for this duplicate question.