# Irreducibility of $x^n+x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

When constructing irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$, one notices that $x^2+x+1$, $x^3+x+1$, and $x^4+x+1$ are irreducible, but $x^5+x+1=(x^3+x^2+1)(x^2+x+1)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. It is natural to ask for which positive integers $n$, the trinomial $x^n+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. The list of such $n$ is tabulated  in OEIS as the sequence [A002475.](https://oeis.org/A002475)

I understand that there is no reasonable pattern we can predict in this sequence of values of $n$. However, I wonder whether the following questions have been studied in the literature:

**Problem 1.** Are there infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $x^n+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$?

**Problem 2.** Are there infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $x^n+x+1$ is a reducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$?

Thank you!

Comment: 2. If $n=2^k$ and $k\ge3$, then the polynomial is reducible.

Comment: @user26857 Wow, that is nice! Thank you. Can you say a few words about the proof of this result? Feel free to expand on your comment in an answer box.

Comment: No need to expand, this has been asked very often, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/729109/the-reducibility-of-polynomial-x2nx1-over-z-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) for example and the duplicates linked to to.

Comment: Cf. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995870902640

Comment: @Dietrich Thank you! I see that Problem 2 has indeed been discussed at great length on the website, although I have yet to see Problem 1 being addressed (but I will look more closely).

Comment: Well, even more when $n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ we have $x^n+x+1$ is divisible by $x^2+x+1$ (over $\mathbb{Z}$!) because $x^3-1=(x^2+x+1)(x-1)$ allows you to "subtract 3 from $n$".  So you can only look for $n\equiv 0,1\pmod{3}$ in 1 as a start.

Comment: For more examples, $x^6+x+1$ and $x^7+x+1$ are irreducible. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2690993/11619) I explain why $x^{127}+x+1$ and $x^{2^{127}-1}+x+1$ are irreducible. My guess would be that it is not known whether there are infinitely many irreducible polynomials of this form. A statistical argument suggest that to be the case though. After all, a random degree $n$ polynomial is irreducible with roughly the probability $1/n$. Here we have a single polynomial of degree $n$ for all $n$, and the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty1/n$ diverges, so....