# Reducibility of $x^q -x -1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q}$

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I came across the following excercise and do not know how to go about this. Given the polynomial $x^q -x -1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{q}$.

- Consider $q=8$. Show this polynomial is reducible by considering an extension on $F_{q}$ in which $\alpha^3 =1$.
- Show that for all $q$, the given polynomial has no roots.

I am quite stuck and fail to come up with any reasonable plan or insight. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The first part is also a special case of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/508920/11619).

Answer (score 3):

*Hint for the second point:* It follows from Lagrange's theorem in group theory that all elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ are roots of $x^q-x$.

Answer (score 1):

A hint for the first part: If $\alpha^3=1$, then $\alpha^8=\alpha^5=\alpha^2$. Furthermore,
$$\alpha^3-1=(\alpha-1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1).$$